# C++: How do I correct the read access violation that my code does

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector

I am beginner at C++ and have been trying to figure a few things out on my own. I am supposed to be writing a code for a function that accepts a vector of pointers to a certain object, go through the list, and delete the invalid date from the list.
So far, when testing, I keep getting an error that reads: "Exception thrown: read access violation" and I have been trying for the past few days to find the error, to no avail.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Reminder
{
private:
    int m_day;
    int m_month;
    string m_description;
    bool value;

public:

    Reminder(int day, int month, string description) : m_day(day), m_month(month), m_description(description)
    {

    }

    string toString()
    {
        stringstream sin;
        sin << m_month << "/" << m_day << ": " << m_description<<endl;
        return sin.str();
    }

    int getDay()
    {
        int day = m_day;
        return day;
    }

    int getMonth()
    {
        int month = m_month;
        return month;
    }



};

vector<Reminder*> removeInvalidDate(vector<Reminder*>& list)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < list.size(); count++)
    {
        if ((list[count]->getDay() < 1) || (list[count]->getDay() > 31))
            delete list[count];
        if ((list[count]->getMonth() < 1) || (list[count]->getMonth() > 12))
            delete list[count];
        else
            ;
    }

    return list;
}

int main()
{
    Reminder reminder1(7, 16, "Final Exam Due");
    Reminder reminder2(7, 4, "Independence Day Holiday");
    Reminder reminder3(1, 1, "Start of the New Year");
    Reminder reminder4(7, 30, "My Birthday");
    Reminder reminder5(1, -9, "Impossible Day1");
    Reminder reminder6(0, 0, "Impossible Day0");
    Reminder reminder7(0, 35, "Impossible day3");
    Reminder reminder8(13, 0, "Impossible");

    Reminder* pRe;
    pRe = new Reminder(reminder1);

    vector<Reminder*> list;

    list.push_back(pRe);

    pRe = new Reminder(reminder2);
    list.push_back(pRe);

    pRe = new Reminder(reminder3);
    list.push_back(pRe);

    pRe = new Reminder(reminder4);
    list.push_back(pRe);

    pRe = new Reminder(reminder5);
    list.push_back(pRe);

    pRe = new Reminder(reminder6);
    list.push_back(pRe);

    pRe = new Reminder(reminder7);
    list.push_back(pRe);

    pRe = new Reminder(reminder8);
    list.push_back(pRe);

    removeInvalidDate(list);

    return 0;
}
```

I think that the issue is either in setting up and passing the vector or in one of the class constructors.

Comment: `vector<Reminder*>` is a bit silly since you don't need any heap allocations here, just use `vector<Reminder>`. `delete list[count];` frees the allocation but doesn't remove the pointer from the vector. `removeInvalidDate()` unnecessarily returns a copy of the vector.

Comment: There is no need for any pointer usage or manual memory allocation in your program.

Comment: *I am beginner at C++ and have been trying to figure a few things out on my own* -- Also, C++ is a very complex language, if not one of the most complex high-level languages to learn.  Using peer-reviewed C++ books is the ideal way to learn C++.

Comment: Unless you have good coaching in the subject, you should consider `new`, `delete`, and other forms of manual memory management to be an advanced topic and save them for when you have the basics of C++ well in hand.

Answer (score 2):

If both the day and the month are invalid, you're deleting list[count] twice

```
if ((list[count]->getDay() < 1) || (list[count]->getDay() > 31))
    delete list[count];
if ((list[count]->getMonth() < 1) || (list[count]->getMonth() > 12))
    delete list[count];
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think that the issue is either in setting up and passing the vector or in one of the class constructors.

Well, you can *test* both hypothesis. And you should actually do this!

Firstly, you can test whether your constructors are causing a problem by simplifying your code to use `vector<int>`. Just say the integer value is the day and leave out the month part for now.

Secondly, you can set up the *minimal* vector with the simplest possible code - and just one element. Or zero elements. And then add elements back until the problem recurs.

This kind of work, testing your understanding of the code, is perfectly normal and a good habit to start.

Neither of those hypotheses will fix your current problem, but I'd encourage you to go back and do them anyway.

This code

```
    if ((list[count]->getDay() < 1) || (list[count]->getDay() > 31))
        delete list[count];
    if ((list[count]->getMonth() < 1) || (list[count]->getMonth() > 12))
        delete list[count];
    else
        ;
```

has two main problems. The first is that the layout suggests you *intend*

```
    if (X)
        A;
    elif (Y)
        B;
    else
        ;
```

but C++ doesn't *have* an `elif`. If you don't want to remove the same element twice, it should be something like

```
    if ((list[count]->getDay() < 1) || (list[count]->getDay() > 31))
    {
        delete list[count];
        continue;
    }
    if ((list[count]->getMonth() < 1) || (list[count]->getMonth() > 12))
    {
        delete list[count];
        continue;
    }
```

(or `if () { ... } else if () { ... }` or whatever).

The second and more serious problem is that `delete list[count]` is *not* how you remove elements from any container in C++. It's roughly how you'd do it in Python. In C++ though, after `delete list[count]`, the element `list[count]` still exists but is a dangling pointer to the storage you just `delete`-d, and may never legally be dereferenced. Since the very next thing you do is dereference it (for the month check), this causes your read access violation.

Any good book will tell you that [`std::vector::erase`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) is how you remove elements from a vector, and that you should prefer [`std::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) to that, and that you should avoid storing (owning) raw pointers in containers in the first place.